# How can I use a Resource as a string parameter?

Tags: vb.net

I want to use an XML-File for my Dataset to save changes.

```
datatable.ReadXml("C:\test.xml")
```

works fine. But I want to use an Xml Resource file. So I tried

```
Dim xmlDoc as String
xmlDoc = MyApplication.My.Resources.xmlTestFile
datatable.ReadXml(xmlDoc)
```

gives me the error `Illigal sign in path` and debugging shows me that `xmlDoc` is empty.

Could anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReadXml requires a filename not content

use

```
Dim ds As New DataSet()
Using stringReader As New StringReader(.......RESOURCE.HERE.......)
ds = New DataSet()
ds.ReadXml(stringReader)
End Using
Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works for ReadXml but not for WriteXml. Do you know why, since writexml requires a filename as well.